tmux session keep being paused when ssh disconnected
I am running rust code in the remote server. I need to run the program for a few days to process data, so I want to run the script detached even after I close my IDE. I'm using vscode and working in the ssh connection.
I ran cargo run in tmux session, detached this session with ctrl+b d, and closed my vscode. However, when I opened my vscode again and attached the session, I found the rust process was totally paused. The process is alive (PID is alive), but it is totally paused with no logging since I closed my vscode and no output result. And I cannot make this process resume running.

I have no clue why this is happening, especially why the process just pauses this way instead of killing itself when I close the vscode.

Will there be a way to deal with this? When I did some research, I found that Lingering could be an issue, but I'm unsure if it's relevant.

Will running with nohup  will run the program background without this issue?


Thanks for the help.
*My remote server is Almalinux 9.

Just to be clear, did you run tmux on the remote server after ssh-ing into it?

@Locke Yes, I ran tmux on the remote server after ssh

It solved when I set up lingering. Still unsure why the process 'stops running' instead of 'being killed', if it was lingering issue.

Can you elaborate on what 'lingering' is?

@KirillKay It's to prevent process to be killed after logging out from the server. Mine was strange - tmux terminals and python processes were still alive when I logged in again, but they stopped working. But anyway, loginctl enable-linger $USER This one line solved my issue. So...
